# Letting typescript warn against accessing first item of possibly empty array

Tags: typescript

```
const test: string[] = [];
test[0].length
```

This code does not throw a TypeScript error. How can you let typescript warn against the fact that a string might actually not exist at a given index?

Comment: I don't think that's typescript's responsibility

Comment: Shouldn't it warn that an item at any index could be either a string or undefined? And since that's obviously not the default, what's the best way to manually configure that?

Comment: Very relevant issue in Github: [micosoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778).  It's still open and awaiting feedback, and some of the discussion in there involves what people have done to deal with the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this workaround, setting array items as possible undefined:

```js
const test: (string | undefined)[] = [];

test[0].length; // error

if(test[0]) {
  test[0].length; // good
}
```

I didn't find any eslint rule which can answer to this need :(

Comment: But in this case `.map(item => item.length)` will also warn right? Having to assert there is not desirable.

Comment: Hmm yep you're right. I don't know good solution to this issue...

Comment: @Gersom TypeScript doesn't do a good job [distinguishing "missing" from "present-but-`undefined`"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).   So `Array<string | undefined>` adequately describes "numeric-keyed property might be missing" but also matches "numeric-keyed property might be `undefined`" as in `["hey", undefined, "you"]`.  So `.map()` needs to handle `undefined` also.  If you want a different solution you'd basically have to redefine all the `Array` type definitions. I might be able to come up with something, but `Array<string | undefined>` is a pretty good answer.

Comment: Update: I can't come up with anything remotely reasonable for this other than `Array<string | undefined>`.